# What is the remainder when ${13}^7$ is divided by 9

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

As the question stated, what is the remainder when ${13}^7$ is divided by 9? There are quite a few online questions similar to this. However, I do not really understand the concept of it.

I have attempted this question by looking for a pattern (as suggested in some online search):

${13}^1 / 9$ = 4 remainder

${13}^2 / 9$ = 7 remainder

${13}^3 / 9$ = 1 remainder

${13}^4 / 9$ = 4 remainder

...

There is clearly a pattern of 4, 7, 1 before it repeats itself in the power 4. For power 7, the remainder is therefore 4. I believe the answer to this question is 4 remainder.

My question is how will I approach if the power is much larger than power 7? Say, if we have ${13}^{100}$ divide by 9, is it right to find the remainder using this method:

$100 / 3 = 33.33333 $

Since $33 * 3 = 99$, for the remainder at the 100th power, it will be 4.

Is there a more elegant way of doing this?

Edit:

Actually, this method does not seem to work if the divisible value is larger than 13. Any idea?

Comment: could you explain (perhaps with a numerical example) what you mean by "this method does not seem to work if the divisible value is larger than $13$"?

Comment: So with ${13^1} / 9$, I am able to obtain remainder of 4. But say if the whole thing becomes divisible by a value larger than 13 (instead of 9), say 15, then ${13}^1 / 15$ do not give me a remainder (I get back 13/15 in calculator). Reason why I said this is because I rely on calculator to check. And $13/9$ returns a mixed fraction which has a remainder. I do think what I said is somewhat flaw - I am still trying to understand. If you can tell me if $13/15$ is possible, that will be great.

Comment: modulo $15$, the remainders of powers of $13$ are $13$, $4$, $7$, $1$, $13$, $4$, $7$, $1$, ...   Does that answer your question?  I'm still not sure I understood your question

Comment: Ah, I see! I think I see where I am wrong now - I have to do it via modulo instead of tradition divide.

Comment: The "more elegant way" is to use [modular order reduction](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2033681/242)  as in the dupe. Here $a=13\equiv 2^2$ has order $e=3$ since $\phi(3^2) = (3\!-\!1)3 = 6\ $ so $\, (2^2)^3\equiv 2^6\equiv 1$ by Euler's phi (totient) theorem (or by  direct calculation)

Answer (score 0):

The pattern you found is that the answer for $13^n$ depends on what residue you get from dividing $n$ by 3: if it's 1 the answer is 4, if it's 2, the answer is 7, if it's 0 the answer is 1.

Now I avoided using the language of group theory but that's ultimately what you need to learn. What happens here is that for any integers $n$ and $m$, $n$ has finite order modulo $m$, and a classical problem is to find that order. You can learn for example that this order divides $\varphi(m)$ where $\varphi$ is the Euler totient function; this is a direct consequence of Lagrange's theorem in group theory.

In this language what your computations show is that 13 has order 3 modulo 9, and that's why the exponent only matters modulo 3.

Answer (score 0):

From
$$13^n=(4+9)^n=4^n+n\cdot 4^{n-1}\cdot 9+\frac{n(n-1)}2\cdot 4^{n-2}\cdot 9^2+\cdots$$
it clearly follows
$$13^n\ mod\ 9=4^n\ mod\ 9$$
Next
$$\left((remainder\ 4)\cdot 4=16\right)\ mod\ 9=7$$
$$\left((remainder\ 7)\cdot 4=28\right)\ mod\ 9=1$$
$$\left((remainder\ 1)\cdot 4=4\right)\ mod\ 9=4$$
Thus your periodicity observation is proved correct.

$$$$
Wrt. to the $100/3$ bit of your question, that one in turn can be given as $100\ mod\ 3=1$.

--- rk

Comment: I did thought that 100/3 is remainder 4. At 99, it will be 1 hence at 100 it will be 4 (cycle repeats). However, I realised this method seem to be flawed too - if the divisible value is larger than the base value then this method can't seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

**Warning**. I am using the notation of [modular arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic), which is particularly convenient for your problem.

Since $13 \equiv 4 \bmod 9$, one has $13^n \equiv 4^n =2^{2n}\bmod 9$. Thus it suffices to compute the sequence $u_n = 2^n \bmod 9$. It is easy to compute this periodic sequence if you observe that $2^3 \equiv -1 \bmod 9$:
\begin{align}
u_0 &= 1, &u_1 &= 2, &u_2 &= 4, \\
u_3 &= -1\equiv 8, &u_4&= -2 \equiv 7, &u_5&=-4 \equiv 5, \\
u_6 &= 1, &&\text{etc.}
\end{align}
In particular, $u_{14} = u_2 = 4$ and thus $13^7 \equiv 4 \bmod 9$. Moreover, as you predicted, the sequence $u_{2n}$ has period $3$: $1, 4, 7, 1, \ldots$.

Answer (score 0):

If you see empirically a pattern so you can cut (a partition of  $\mathbb{N}$) $\mathbb{N}$ like follow. $$\mathbb{N}=\{3k , k \in \mathbb{N}\}\cup\{3k+1 , k \in \mathbb{N}\}\cup\{3k+2, k \in \mathbb{N}\}$$

Let $k \in \mathbb{N}$

Because $$ 4^{3k} \equiv 64^k \equiv 1^k \equiv1 \mod9 $$

We get :
$$ 13^{3k}\equiv 4^{3k}\equiv 1  \mod 9 \\
 13^{3k+1}\equiv 4^{3k+1}\equiv 4  \mod 9 \\
 13^{3k+2}\equiv 4^{3k+2}\equiv 16 \equiv7  \mod 9 \\$$

So the cycle is verified. And because :

$$  7=3*2+1$$

The remainder of the division of $13^7 $ by $9$ is $4$.